# lepture/Authlib Client Not Work for OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow

Tags: python, flask, oauth, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm trying to implement an OAuth2 Provider and client using [Authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/). I follow the docs to write the provider and it seems it is correct, but the client after being redirected to authentication page and the confirmation to access the resources is given successfully, I got the following error: {"error": "invalid_grant"}. Unfortunately, I couldn't find why.

Here my code:

**models.py**

```py
from pony.orm import *
from authlib.oauth2.rfc6749 import ClientMixin

db = Database()

class User(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    username = Required(str)
    password = Required(str)
    clients = Set("Client")
    tokens = Set("Token")

    def get_user_id(self):
        return self.id

    def get_username(self):
        return self.name    


class Client(db.Entity, ClientMixin):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    client_id = Required(str)
    client_secret = Required(str)
    redirect_url = Required(str)
    users = Set("User")
    tokens = Set("Token")

    def check_redirect_uri(self, redirect_uri): 
        print "Client::check_redirect_uri:", redirect_uri
        return True

    def check_response_type(self, response_type):
        print "Client::check_response_type: ", response_type
        return response_type in ["authorization_code", "code", "password"]

#Authorization token
class Token(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    value = Required(str)
    user = Required("User")
    client = Required("Client")
    scope = Optional(str)


@db_session
def create_new_user(name, username, password):
    user = User(name=name, username=username, password=password)
    commit()

@db_session
def create_new_client(name, client_id, client_secret, redirect_url):
    client = Client(name=name, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, redirect_url=redirect_url)
    commit()



from authlib.oauth2.rfc6749 import grants
from authlib.common.security import generate_token

class AuthorizationCodeGrant(grants.AuthorizationCodeGrant):

    @db_session
    def create_authorization_code(self, client, grant_user, request):
        code = generate_token(48)
        token = Token(value=token, user=User[int(grant_user.get_user_id)],
                      client=Client[int(client.client_id)], scope=request.scope)
        commit()
        print "AuthorizationCodeGrant::create_authorization_code: token:", token
        return code

    def parse_authorization_code(self, code, client):
        print "AuthorizationCodeGrant::parse_authorization_code"
        token = Token.select(lambda t: t.value == code and t.client_id == client.client_id).first()
        return token

    def delete_authorization_code(self, authorization_code):
        print "AuthorizationCodeGrant::delete autorization code: ", authorization_code.user_id

    def authenticate_user(self, authorization_code):
        print "authenticate_user"
        return User[int(authorization_code.user_id)]


db.bind(provider='sqlite', filename='database.sqlite', create_db=True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
set_sql_debug(True)
```

**server.py**

```py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@db_session
def query_client(client_id):
    print "query_client id", client_id
    client = Client.select(lambda c: c.client_id == client_id).first()
    return client

@db_session
def save_token(token_data, request):
    if request.user:
        user_id = request.user.get_user_id()
        print "user_id", user_id
    else:
        user_id = request.client.user_id
        print "user_id", user_id
    client =   Client[int(request.client.client_id)]
    user =  User[int(user_id)]
    token = Token(user=user, client=client)
    commit()


server = AuthorizationServer(
    query_client=query_client,
    save_token=save_token,
)

#AuthorizationCodeGrant defindo em models.py
server.register_grant(AuthorizationCodeGrant)
from authlib.flask.oauth2 import ResourceProtector

require_oauth = ResourceProtector()


def current_user():
    if 'id' in session:
        uid = session['id']
        try:
            return User[int(uid)]
        except:
            return None    
    return None


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@db_session
def index():
    if session['id']:
        user = current_user()
        return render_template('user.html', user=user)
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@db_session
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if session['id']:
            user = current_user()
            return render_template('user.html', user=user)
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        username = request.form['username']
        user = User.select(lambda c: c.username == username).first()
        if user:
            session['id'] = user.id
            return render_template('user.html', user=user)
        else:
            return render_template('error.html', msg="Usuario nao encontrado")    


@app.route('/newlogin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('newlogin.html')
    else:
        name = request.form['name']
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        create_new_user(name, username, password)
        return redirect("/")

@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def logout():
    session['id'] = None
    return redirect('/')


@app.route('/clients', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@db_session
def clients():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       name = request.form['name']
       client_id = gen_salt(24)
       client_secret = gen_salt(48)
       redirect_url = request.form['redirecturl']
       create_new_client(name, client_id, client_secret, redirect_url=redirect_url)

    clients = Client.select()
    return render_template('clients.html', clients=clients)


@app.route('/oauth/authorize', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@db_session
def authorize():
    user = current_user()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            grant = server.validate_consent_request(end_user=user)
            print "Server: /authorize: grant:"
            pprint(vars(grant))
        except OAuth2Error as error:
            return error.error
        return render_template('authorize.html', user=user, grant=grant)
    if not user and 'username' in request.form:
        username = request.form.get('username')
        user = User.select(lambda u: u.username == username).first()
    if request.form['confirm']:
        grant_user = user
    else:
        grant_user = None
    print "Server: /authorize: grant_user:", grant_user    
    return server.create_authorization_response(grant_user=grant_user)

@app.route('/oauth/token', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def issue_token():
    return server.create_token_response()

@app.route('/user/profile')
@require_oauth("profile")
def get_profile():
    return jsonify(current_user())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os 
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = 'true'
    os.environ['AUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] ='1'
    app.debug = True
    app.secret_key = 'development'
    server.init_app(app)
    app.run()
```

**client.py**

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
oauth = OAuth(app)

client = oauth.register(
    name='ecl-app1',
    client_id='wKbpjHNvSSeirBO9SzYdWOg4',
    client_secret='1SNDG8hxpNjP2rrlapVAPy8d9CHdVQ8Kzd4NqHydV7VdIrv7',
    access_token_url='http://localhost:5000/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='http://localhost:5000/oauth/authorize',
    api_base_url='http://localhost:5000/',
    grant_type='code',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'profile'},
)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)

    print "App Client: index: redirect_uri:", redirect_uri
    resp = client.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
    print "App Client: index: authorize_redirect: ", resp
    #print(resp.status)
    #print(resp.headers)
    #print(resp.get_data())
    return client.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    print "App Client: authorize:"
    token = client.authorize_access_token()
    # you can save the token into database
    profile = client.get('/user')
    return "ok"




if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os 
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = 'true'
    os.environ['AUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] ='1'
    app.debug = True
    app.secret_key = 'development'
    app.run(port=9000)
```

Comment: which part does "invalid_grant" appear? Is it `POST /oauth/authorize`? Beside, can you provide your OS, Python environments and Authlib version?

Comment: Yes, in the authorize() method the invalid grant appears, in the "return server.create_authorization_response(grant_user=grant_user)". I'm using Ubuntu, python 2.7.

Comment: If it works, you can mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the whole code. But from the information you provided, I guess it is caused by not passing `response_type` into the POST request.

Make sure your HTML template contains the requested `response_type` fields, it is also ok if `response_type` is in the URL.

Check your code with:

```
print(request.args)
print(request.form)
```

Make sure `response_type` is in there.

Comment: Yeap! I couldn't find "response_type" on POST request.

Comment: @EduardoLopes then, make sure there is a `response_type` in form.